# Scaled Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

if I define the transform ($\epsilon \ll 1$)

$$\hat f(\omega) = \int f(t)e^{\frac{i\omega t}{\epsilon^2}}dt,$$

is the inverse transform

$$f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int \hat f(\omega)e^{-\frac{i\omega t}{\epsilon^2}}d\omega$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$\hat f_\epsilon(\omega) = \int f(t)e^{\frac{i\omega t}{\epsilon^2}}dt.$$

Then $\hat f_\epsilon(\omega) = \hat f_1(\omega/\epsilon^2),$ with $\hat f_1$ being the unscaled transform. Thus, $\hat f_1(\omega) = \hat f_\epsilon(\epsilon^2\omega).$

Using the inverse transform we get
$$
f(t) 
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \hat f_1(\omega) e^{-i\omega t} \, d\omega
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \hat f_\epsilon(\epsilon^2\omega) e^{-i\omega t} \, d\omega.
$$
Making the substitution $\omega'=\epsilon^2\omega$ we then get
$$
f(t)
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \hat f_\epsilon(\omega') e^{-i\omega' t/\epsilon^2} \, d\omega'/\epsilon^2
= \frac{1}{2\pi\epsilon^2} \int \hat f_\epsilon(\omega') e^{-i\omega' t/\epsilon^2} \, d\omega'.
$$
Thus your inversion formula is missing a factor $\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}.$